# How to programmatically execute a command in eshell?

Tags: elisp, eshell

I want to execute simple commands in `eshell` without explicitly typing them into the prompt, using something like `with-current-buffer` How can I do this?

Comment: Can you expand your question? It's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: Are you interested in using `comint-send-string` and then `comint-send-input` once the prior string has been sent?

Comment: `eshell` does not use `comint`, that complicates it a bit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My initial hunch was looking for an official command that does this already, so I've found `eshell-command`.  However that outputs to a separate buffer, so it's not an option.

Here's an example with `ls` and an `*eshell*` buffer:

```
(with-current-buffer "*eshell*"
  (eshell-return-to-prompt)
  (insert "ls")
  (eshell-send-input))
```

Comment: caisah mentioned `with-current-buffer` in the question, so isn't `eshell-command` *precisely* what is wanted? (although re-reading, I see it's not actually clear which buffer is supposed to be current).

Comment: I assume the context to be an already existing `eshell` buffer where one can already enter commands to execute them.  However there isn't any primitive to execute stuff in that buffer programmatically as if one wrote it, `eshell-command` behaves slightly different since its output cannot be obtained by normally using `eshell`.

Comment: I am having `(error "No buffer named *eshell*")` and can I call this through a keybinding for the latest opened buffer?

Comment: @alper replace the string literal `"*eshell*"` with a call to `(eshell)` which will return the Eshell buffer (creating it if necessary).

Answer (score 3):

The following proposed solution is intended to permit users to send input programmatically underneath the `eshell` hood, rather than inserting the command into the `eshell` buffer following command prompt.  @lawlist has submitted a feature request for the Emacs development team to consider: http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25270

**SAMPLE USAGE**:  `(eshell-send-input nil nil nil "ls -la /")`

```lisp
(require 'eshell)

(defun eshell-send-input (&optional use-region queue-p no-newline input-string-a)
  "Send the input received to Eshell for parsing and processing.
After `eshell-last-output-end', sends all text from that marker to
point as input.  Before that marker, calls `eshell-get-old-input' to
retrieve old input, copies it to the end of the buffer, and sends it.
-  If USE-REGION is non-nil, the current region (between point and mark)
will be used as input.
-  If QUEUE-P is non-nil, input will be queued until the next prompt,
rather than sent to the currently active process.  If no process, the
input is processed immediately.
-  If NO-NEWLINE is non-nil, the input is sent without an implied final
newline."
  (interactive "P")
  ;; Note that the input string does not include its terminal newline.
  (let ((proc-running-p
          (and (eshell-interactive-process)
               (not queue-p)))
        (inhibit-point-motion-hooks t)
        after-change-functions)
    (unless (and proc-running-p
                 (not (eq (process-status (eshell-interactive-process)) 'run)))
      (if (or proc-running-p
              (>= (point) eshell-last-output-end))
        (goto-char (point-max))
        ;; This is for a situation when point is before `point-max'.
        (let ((copy (or input-string-a (eshell-get-old-input use-region))))
          (goto-char eshell-last-output-end)
          (insert-and-inherit copy)))
      (unless (or no-newline
                  (and eshell-send-direct-to-subprocesses
                       proc-running-p))
        (insert-before-markers-and-inherit ?\n))
      (if proc-running-p
        (progn
          (eshell-update-markers eshell-last-output-end)
          (if (or eshell-send-direct-to-subprocesses
                  (= eshell-last-input-start eshell-last-input-end))
            (unless no-newline
              (process-send-string (eshell-interactive-process) "\n"))
                (process-send-region (eshell-interactive-process)
                   eshell-last-input-start
                   eshell-last-input-end)))
        (if (and (null input-string-a) (= eshell-last-output-end (point)))
          ;; This next line is for a situation when nothing is there --
          ;; i.e., just make a new command prompt.
          (run-hooks 'eshell-post-command-hook)
          (let (input)
            (eshell-condition-case err
              (progn
                (setq input (or input-string-a
                                (buffer-substring-no-properties
                                   eshell-last-output-end (1- (point)))))
                (run-hook-with-args 'eshell-expand-input-functions
                        eshell-last-output-end (1- (point)))
                (let ((cmd (eshell-parse-command-input
                             eshell-last-output-end (1- (point)) nil input-string-a)))
                  (when cmd
                    (eshell-update-markers eshell-last-output-end)
                    (setq input (buffer-substring-no-properties
                                  eshell-last-input-start
                                  (1- eshell-last-input-end)))
                    (run-hooks 'eshell-input-filter-functions)
                    (and (catch 'eshell-terminal
                           (ignore
                             (if (eshell-invoke-directly cmd)
                               (eval cmd)
                               (eshell-eval-command cmd input))))
                         (eshell-life-is-too-much)))))
                  (quit
                    (eshell-reset t)
                    (run-hooks 'eshell-post-command-hook)
                    (signal 'quit nil))
                  (error
                    (eshell-reset t)
                    (eshell-interactive-print
                      (concat (error-message-string err) "\n"))
                    (run-hooks 'eshell-post-command-hook)
                    (insert-and-inherit input)))))))))

(defun eshell-parse-command-input (beg end &optional args input-string-b)
  "Parse the command input from BEG to END.
The difference is that `eshell-parse-command' expects a complete
command string (and will error if it doesn't get one), whereas this
function will inform the caller whether more input is required.
-  If nil is returned, more input is necessary (probably because a
multi-line input string wasn't terminated properly).  Otherwise, it
will return the parsed command."
  (let (delim command)
    (if (setq delim (catch 'eshell-incomplete
                      (ignore
                        (setq command
                              (eshell-parse-command
                                (cons beg end) args t input-string-b)))))
      (ignore
        (message "Expecting completion of delimiter %c ..."
          (if (listp delim)
              (car delim)
            delim)))
      command)))

(defun eshell-parse-command (command &optional args toplevel input-string-c)
  "Parse the COMMAND, adding ARGS if given.
COMMAND can either be a string, or a cons cell demarcating a buffer
region.  TOPLEVEL, if non-nil, means that the outermost command (the
user's input command) is being parsed, and that pre and post command
hooks should be run before and after the command."
  (let* (
      eshell--sep-terms
      (terms
        (if input-string-c
          (eshell-parse-arguments--temp-buffer input-string-c)
          (append
            (if (consp command)
              (eshell-parse-arguments (car command) (cdr command))
              (let ((here (point))
                    (inhibit-point-motion-hooks t))
                (with-silent-modifications
                  ;; FIXME: Why not use a temporary buffer and avoid this
                  ;; "insert&delete" business?  --Stef
                  (insert command)
                  (prog1
                      (eshell-parse-arguments here (point))
                    (delete-region here (point))))))
            args)))
      (commands
        (mapcar
          (function
            (lambda (cmd)
              (setq cmd (if (or (not (car eshell--sep-terms))
                                (string= (car eshell--sep-terms) ";"))
                          (eshell-parse-pipeline cmd)
                          `(eshell-do-subjob
                              (list ,(eshell-parse-pipeline cmd)))))
              (setq eshell--sep-terms (cdr eshell--sep-terms))
              (if eshell-in-pipeline-p
                cmd
                `(eshell-trap-errors ,cmd))))
          (eshell-separate-commands terms "[&;]" nil 'eshell--sep-terms))) )
    (let ((cmd commands))
      (while cmd
        (if (cdr cmd)
            (setcar cmd `(eshell-commands ,(car cmd))))
        (setq cmd (cdr cmd))))
    (if toplevel
      `(eshell-commands (progn
                                (run-hooks 'eshell-pre-command-hook)
                                (catch 'top-level (progn ,@commands))
                                (run-hooks 'eshell-post-command-hook)))
      (macroexp-progn commands))))

(defun eshell-parse-arguments--temp-buffer (input-string-d)
  "Parse all of the arguments at point from BEG to END.
Returns the list of arguments in their raw form.
Point is left at the end of the arguments."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert input-string-d)
    (let ((inhibit-point-motion-hooks t)
          (args (list t))
          delim)
      (with-silent-modifications
        (remove-text-properties (point-min) (point-max)
                                '(arg-begin nil arg-end nil))
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (if (setq
             delim
             (catch 'eshell-incomplete
               (while (not (eobp))
                 (let* ((here (point))
                        (arg (eshell-parse-argument)))
                   (if (= (point) here)
                       (error "Failed to parse argument '%s'"
                              (buffer-substring here (point-max))))
                   (and arg (nconc args (list arg)))))))
            (throw 'eshell-incomplete (if (listp delim)
                                          delim
                                        (list delim (point) (cdr args)))))
        (cdr args)))))
```

Comment: Is it possible to make a keybinding to call eshell-send-input? ex:  `(defun foo () (interactive)(eshell-send-input nil nil nil "ls"))` and keybinding to call foo ?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function for it,

```lisp
(defun run-this-in-eshell (cmd)
  "Runs the command 'cmd' in eshell."
  (with-current-buffer "*eshell*"
    (eshell-kill-input)
    (end-of-buffer)
    (insert cmd)
    (eshell-send-input)
    (end-of-buffer)
    (yank)
    ))
```

It will first kill the input already present, run `cmd` and then yank the input that was present back.

Answer (score 0):

`Package-install RET eshell-toggle`, then use this piece of code as a function or whatever.

```
(progn
  (eshell-toggle)
  (eshell-return-to-prompt)
  (insert *command*)
  (eshell-send-input))
```